# Symfony 2.8 save roles to database and dynamically allocated to users

Tags: symfony, dynamic, acl, roles

I use Symfony 2.8, I have read the cookbook about voters and advanced ACL.
But now, I can't find how to save these config roles(or voters's attributes) to database.

I also don't want hard code the permission in every controller.I want these dynamic via web page.

Comment: Who can give a basic demo?

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39198846/symfony3-how-to-store-user-roles-in-database) might help you too

Answer (score 0):

Symfony permission works through [Voter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html). Whether you use `ACL` or not, you must integrate voter to work along with permissions.

Your voter class can also have the logic of permission stored, and you can create number of Voter classes as per your need / architecture.

So, As you asked, to store the permission logic in the database. `ACL` comes into picture. See [the document](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/acl_advanced.html) on how to integrate `Advanced ACL`. Its bit complicated with custom permission mappings as I have used them.

if you too find it complicated to integrate with current requirement, you can build your own permission entities and fetch with the help of cache and use in voter to detect the authentication.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If use Voter, I don't know how to save the Voter attributes to database .eg. every entity Voter may have attribute  'view','edit,'create','delete''.I want to list all these voter's attributes via the web page and give user these permission.