# Where and how symfony store user roles

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

Hello guys am trying to understand logic in symfony about user and user roles and how its works. Am new in symfony and i follow this tutorial :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html

Everything work perfect in my project but when i look in database i have `user` table and all user what i registred like data in table.

But where is table for user roles ? How symfony know who is `ROLE_ADMIN` and who is `ROLE_MODERATOR`. How can implement to all user has specific roles and save that roles in database where i can change it later from some admin panel?
ACL meybe?

Comment: By default, roles are stored as a column in the user table.  It is actually a serialized array so a use can have have multiple roles.  You can of course make your own implementation and have a user roles table if you feel one is needed.

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39198846/symfony3-how-to-store-user-roles-in-database) might help you too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Symfony is not resposible of storing your roles. You have to store them if you need them to be managed throw an admin console for example.

The `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface` Interface your User entity implements contains a method name `getRoles` that should return either an **array of String** representing the user role or and Array of `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface`.  So you can create an entity in your project named `Role` that implements `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface`. Then link that entity to your User entity throw a **ManyToMany** association. Finally implements the getRoles method that should return the Roles of the given user.

You can then manage your roles as any other entity in your project.

Answer (score 3):

RoleInterface has now been deprecated and is due for removal in 4.0 so you can do the same as Genoud Magloire said but be sure to **extend** `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role`

Here is an example of my role entity.

```
<?php

namespace ExampleCoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * ExampleRole
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="EXAMPLE_ROLE")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ExampleRole extends Role
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 9,
     *      max = 100,
     *      minMessage = "Role name must be at least {{ limit }} characters long",
     *      maxMessage = "Role name cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters"
     * )
     * @ORM\Column(name="ROLE_NAME", type="string", length=255, nullable=false, unique=true)
     *
     */
    private $roleName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Choice({"Y","N"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="GRANTABLE", type="string", length=1, nullable=false)
     */
    private $grantable;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="CREATED_ON", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $createdOn;

    //...and so on with whatever else you want to save. 

    public function __construct( $roleName = null )
    {
        parent::__construct( $roleName );
    }
```